# I’m building a portfolio but the sidebar component is not showing on any of the pages?

Tags: reactjs, sass

The sidebar is not showing on the home page of my portfolio or on any other pages like it’s supposed to be. Im wondering if it’s the CSS or something deeper. I assume the relevant code to this issue is of course the Sidebar component, App.js, and maybe Layout component and the scss file for the sidebar. Does anyone have any advice on how to narrow down as to which few files are likely the problem as it feels like it could be any of the components or their scss is not working together. Anyone know how to fix the sidebar not showing?

Sidebare index.js --->

```
import './index.scss'
import LogoS from '../../assets/images/logo-s.png'
import LogoSubtitle from '../../assets/images/logo_sub.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {
  faLinkedin,
  faGithub,
  faYoutube,
  faSkype,
} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faHome, faUser, faEnvelope, faSuitcase } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="nav-bar">
      <Link className="logo" to="/">
        <img src={LogoS} alt="Logo" />
        <img className="sub-logo" src={LogoSubtitle} alt="slobodan" />
      </Link>
      <nav>
        <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="active" className="about-link" to="/about">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="active" className="portfolio-link" to="/portfolio">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSuitcase} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          activeclassname="active"
          className="contact-link"
          to="/contact"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
      </nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/slobodan-gaji%C4%87-006bb8b8/"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedin} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://github.com/bobangajicsm"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBu5ulO4d-d47lAVybpRTkw"
            rel="noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="skype:live:bobangajicsm" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSkype} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Sidebare scss -->

```
.nav-bar {
  background: #181818;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  min-height: 500px;

  .logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0;

    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 8px auto;
      width: 24px;
      height: auto;

      &.sub-logo {
        width: 50px;
      }
    }
  }

  nav {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 210px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -120px;
    width: 100%;

    a {
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #4d4d4e;
      display: block;
      line-height: 51px;
      height: 51px;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;

      i {
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      }

      &:hover {
        color: #ffd700;

        svg {
          opacity: 0;
        }

        &:after {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }

      &:after {
        content: '';
        font-size: 9px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      }

      &:first-child {
        &:after {
          content: 'HOME';
        }
      }
    }

    a.about-link {
      &:after {
        content: 'ABOUT';
      }
    }

    a.contact-link {
      &:after {
        content: 'CONTACT';
      }
    }

    a.portfolio-link {
      &:after {
        content: 'PORTFOLIO';
      }
    }

    a.active {
      svg {
        color: #ffd700;
      }
    }
  }

  ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;

    li {
      a {
        padding: 7px 0;
        display: block;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 16px;
        color: #4d4d4e;

        &:hover {
          color: #ffd700;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

App.js --->

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard'
import './App.scss'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Layout index.js -->

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar/'
import './index.scss'

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="page">
        <span className="tags top-tags">&lt;body&gt;</span>

        <Outlet />
        <span className="tags bottom-tags">
          &lt;/body&gt;
          <br />
          <span className="bottom-tag-html">&lt;/html&gt;</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

Thank you in advance any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is this path correct: ```import Sidebar from '../Sidebar/'``` ? Can you double check ?

Comment: Yes it's correct I just double checked it

Comment: Can you provide a live URL or sandbox ?